# Parentheses inside Razor code block

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to put a URL.Action call inside a Razor ASP.Net MVC code block at the top of a View which includes a parameter creation - it won't parse and causes an error on the page.
Seen similar questions where they remove the "@" but I've tried that.
I am using an Action for the jpg url as it points to a rewriter.

Code placed at the top of the page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.event_title + " - Event - HOTSHOE";
    ViewBag.MetaDescription = @Model.event_title + " - HOTSHOE";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Hotshoe.cshtml";
    ViewBag.MainImage = Url.Action("thumbnail", "Events" , new { id=Model.event_ID }) + "/imagename.jpg";
}
```

The problematic line is

```
ViewBag.MainImage = Url.Action("thumbnail", "Events" , new { id=Model.event_ID }) + "/imagename.jpg";
```

In the editor it complains

> Syntax Error, ',' expected

Just after Model.event_ID but before the "}".

This code works on another part of the page outside of the code block with @ in front of @Url.Action and @Model.event_ID

When viewing the page it complains:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 7476:        } Line 7477:    } Line 7478:}

Any ideas ? TIA.

Comment: It sounds like there's a broken pairing of some brackets or parentheses  (likely a typo or indentation mistake) somewhere in your *7478 lines of code* in that one file.  It likely doesn't have anything to do with what you're trying to accomplish in the code posted.  You may want to break up that file into smaller, more manageable pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humm i'm not discovering why it doesn't work but...

**Solution**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.event_title + " - Event - HOTSHOE";
    ViewBag.MetaDescription = @Model.event_title + " - HOTSHOE";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Hotshoe.cshtml";
}

@(ViewBag.MainImage = Url.Action("thumbnail", "Events" , new { id=Model.event_ID }) + "/imagename.jpg";)
```

**Edit**

Ok i found the problem.

```
ViewBag.Title = @Model.event_title + " - Event - HOTSHOE";
ViewBag.MetaDescription = @Model.event_title + " - HOTSHOE";
```

Remove the `@` from `@Model.event_title`